# Full Calendar hide month with no events

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

Hy,

I am using [Full Calendar by Arshaw](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/), but unfortunately there is no default option to skip no events month.

What i am trying to achieve is when i press next month in month view is to skip the months that have no events.

Is there any way to make this possible? Any kind of help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Skip the months that have no events, what should happen say user in on  Jan 2014 month and he click on next and there is not no data after Jan  01 2014. Is it possible ? Yes it is, you 'll need to hook in your own custom function on the click of next and previous button, but I would not advice to do something like this unless its a requirement, which again is a little wierd.

Comment: Yeah it's a requirement, what kind of custom function do you have in mind ?

Comment: This http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/ should help you get started

Comment: I have been over that way to many times, the only way i see me doing that is somehow splitting an array of 4000 events by months and checking on every next click if the next month has even and then jump to month that has events.

Answer (score 0):

in viewDisplay callback, add this

```
viewDisplay: function(view) {

    if( $('.fc-event').length == 0 ){
        $('#calendar').fullCalendar('next'); 
    }
}
```

Comment: well this will remove your ability to go back (previous button). What do you want to happen when clicking "back" ?

Comment: Already tried this, it won't work also because if there are 3 months without events it will take 1 min to load

Comment: How many events there are in each month? Consider loading all your events at once. I have a calendar with about 2000 events in total and works fine. I don't think that it is better to fetch the events in each month change...

Comment: Over 4000 events it takes like 2 minutes to load them all in calendar :(